# x-editable typeahead ajax source

Tags: ajax, typeahead, x-editable

I don't want to print all the cities in my code `local: ['LONDON', 'BERLIN', 'NEW YORK', 'MADRID']`. i would like to make query each time user type a letter.

Can I use ajax in order to use Auto complete with "x-editable typeahead"?

HTML:

```
<li><label class="control-label">CITY:</label> <span id="userCity" data-
type="typeaheadjs" data-pk="cityID" data-name="users">PARIS</span></li>
```

JS:

```
$('#userCity').editable({
    url: 'ajax/editUser.php',
    typeahead: {
        local: ['LONDON', 'BERLIN', 'NEW YORK', 'MADRID']
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this may help someone, looks like the current 1.5.1 release of the X-Editable does not support passing the `dataset` parameter to the typeahead constructor.  There is a pull request which implements support for this documented here https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/pull/664.

To quickly get around this issue, you will need to update the `inputs-ext/typeaheadjs/typeaheadjs.js` at around line 45 to be:

```
this.$input.typeahead.apply(this.$input, this.options.typeahead);
```

Then you can instantiate the X-Editor as:

```
var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    remote: '/url/to/json/output'
    // any other bloodhound options here
});

bloodhound.initialize();

$('#editable-field').editable({
    type: 'typeaheadjs',
    typeahead: [{
        hint: true,
        highlight: true
        // any other typeahead options
    }, {
        source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
        // any other dataset options
    }]
});
```